# Create user with a period in the user name on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos, user-accounts

I need to create users with periods in their names on CentOS7.

For example, joe.blow@foo.com. It looks like this is technically supported but `adduser`/`useradd` have a regex which is preventing this. I've seen people suggest creating them without the periods and then manually adding them in `/etc/passwd` `/etc/shadow` etc. I need to create them in a script so any manual process is ***no bueno***.

It looks like this is possible on Ubuntu as it provides `/etc/adduser.conf` which externally defines the regex used by adduser so that one can customize the behavior.

Any thoughts on how to do this or tools? **Dr. Google** has failed me :-)

Answer (score 0):

If it's for email purposes then you can create normal usernames and use email aliases for period in email address.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up recompiling the CentOS 7 shadow-utils SRPM which has these tools in to so that they would support user names with `@` symbols in them.